# cucumber shows step-def to be implemented even when it is implemented

Tags: angularjs, protractor, cucumberjs

I am using cucumberjs and protractor framework for test my angular website.
I have a question regarding cucumber- everytime I run a single feature using cucumber (example cucumber "feature/abc.feature") it gives me a set of step-definitions that need to implemented for that feature.And it gives me same after I have implemented the step-def also.

Is this usual behavior of cucumber? Why it doesn't evaluate the step-def have been implemented or not?

Cheers

Comment: did you `require` your step definitions in your config file?

Comment: yes I did cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['support/**/*.js', 'step-definitions/**/*.js'],